# Required review if PR contains changes to a specific file

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a repo where approvals are not required and PRs can be merged without approvals. However, I want to implement a rule that will require approvals for a PR if it contains changes to a specific config file. The approval should be from a specific set of people/CODEONWERS in this case.

I read about [rule sets](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-rulesets/about-rulesets), [branch protection rules](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-protected-branches/managing-a-branch-protection-rule) and [managing pull request reviews](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-organization-settings/managing-pull-request-reviews-in-your-organization). However, I couldn't find something related to applying rules for specific PRs(like the case explained above).

Comment: I'm not sure that this is really possible. It is however possible to find out if a file has changed and comment on the PR saying that you should not merge it until it have been reviewed, but there might not be a hard way to enforce it.

Comment: Thanks @MB. I think maybe something along the lines of branch protection rules and CODEOWNERS for specific files might be worth exploring here.